# How to convert tex to docx in algorithm2e

Tags: pandoc

my tex uses algorithm2e environments, when I use pandoc to convert the latex source file to docx file, the content in algorithm2e cannot correctly show in the docx file.

I have tried to search for the proper filter, but no result found.

Who can help me to solve this problem? Thanks so much.

Comment: what does it mean "correctly show"?

Comment: by default, the converted docx only shows the words in the algorithm2e environment, but not the formatted as shown in compiled pdf.